# Export Script as XML

Tags: export, enterprise-architect

I would like to export a search script to an XML file.

When I click `Project -> Model Import/Export -> Export Reference Data`, I get a list of available elements to export. The `Automation Scripts` group is empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to Export Reference Data, you get a list of **types of elements** to export. So when you check Automation Scripts, you will export all your automation scripts (and then you can import them again in another EA project).

In order to save one script, open it in the Script Editor by double-clicking and then save the script as a new file.